# How do i open a case when a specific activity is added

Tags: civicase, civirules, activity

How can I create a case with a set case type when a specific activity is added to a contact or a contact is added to a particular group?

1. New contact joins using WordPress integration form.
2. A new contact is added to a New Members group.
3. New Case added called New member and workflow added.

The part in 3 is the new part I would like. I have CiviRules installed, but I can't find anything that would do what I need in that extension.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it with civirules but in part 1, what integration are you using? Does it have a create case feature?

Comment: I am using Wordpress.

Comment: I meant your post said "WordPress integration form" - what form is that? Is it Caldera forms? A custom form? What page do they go to to "join"?

Comment: Ah ok sorry.
I am using profile shortcodes for the new member form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For wordpress, you might get what you need from the [Form Processor](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor) extension.

Something like this:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Looks good, I will have a look at work tomorrow. Then I'll let you know when I have sorted it. Thank you